# More efficient database access

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, performance, linq-to-sql

I am new to databases and linq, so my problem may be considered trivial. I currently start all my db requests in each class with:

```
 DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext()
```

Then I proceed to make whatever linq request I need within the method and carry on with the main application logic.

Now, two interesting queries:

1) I believe I have seen people wrapping db usage within 'using'. Such as:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    ...
}
```

If this is correct, then doesn't it mean that my class can't use a member 'db' variable anymore, but rather those db requests need to be made within each function call? Also, what exactly would happen if I don't use 'using' within the calls?

2) Running my app with SQL Profiler enabled, I see lots of connections opening and closing. Does this means that each DataClassesDataContext call makes a separate connection? It seems inefficient, so is the right way to actually make the DataClassesDataContext object a static within each class being used?

Comment: There are other frameworks like developer express XPO that support linq type queries.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use one `DataContext` per database conversation. Only you can decide exactly what a conversation is, but typically it is a complete request (fetch the user's wish list, or fetch the user's closed orders, for example) that you might think of as a "unit of work."

Typically what happens is something like this:

```
WishList wishlist;
using(var context = new DataContext(connectionString)) {
    var service = new UserWishListService(context);
    wishlist = service.GetUserWishList();
}
```

> Also, what exactly would happen if I don't use `using` within the calls?

The `DataContext` won't be disposed of properly (unless you've wrapped in a `try-catch-finally`, but generally you should just use `using`).

> Does this means that each `DataClassesDataContext` call makes a separate connection?

Not quite. Your application will benefit from the SQL Server ADO.NET provider's built-in [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). Don't worry about this, let the provider manage it for you.

> It seems inefficient, so is the right way to actually make the `DataClassesDataContext` object a `static` within each class being used?

Absolutely not. `DataContext`s are not thread-safe (in fact, they are thread-unsafe) and this has "there be dragons" written all over it. Additionally, even a single-threaded context, a `static DataContext` is a bad choice because the `DataContext` maintains a cache (for object tracking purposes) of all the entities it has pulled from the database. Over time, the memory consumption will become ginormous.

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the asp.net tag, it means you are using the context within a HTTP call. A static member context is unusable in asp.net because you need to synchronize access to it, and since your data context is required by *every* call, you can only serve one HTTP response at a time, a scalability fiasco of epic proportions.

This is why data context are created and disposed 'on-the-go'. In fact, [the class specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) clearly calls out this use pattern:

> In general, a DataContext instance is
>   designed to last for one "unit of
>   work" however your application defines
>   that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to
>   create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext
>   instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that
>   represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

For ASP.Net a sensible 'unit-of-work' context is the HTTP call itself. A longer discussion on this topic can be found at [Linq to SQL DataContext Lifetime Management](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx).

The issue of connections open/close is a non-issue. Normally the connections are pooled and the 'opening' is nothing but a re-use of a connection from the pool. If you're opening is heavyweight (fully fledged login) then you're using pooling incorrectly. Comparing [Logins/sec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190697.aspx) and [Connection Resets/sec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190697.aspx) counters will quickly reveal if that is indeed the case.