# Is this really how you use Linq-To-Sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, performance, linq-to-sql

I saw an interesting link here about Linq-To-Sql:
[More efficient database access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706766/more-efficient-database-access)

Looking at my own code I realized that I also haven't been disposing the `DataClassesDataContext`. Is this a problem? I don't know, but I went searching through my code and added `using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())` throughout my code.

Now, here is the interesting thing. We log almost every page access and transaction in our code. So I now have a block of code that looks like this:

```
protected WriteLog(String activity)
{
   using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
   {
       ... Do db write with Linq
   }
}
```

This is a very heavily used function, with at least 50 calls/second at any time. So before I assume we suffered from potential 'leaks', which is a problem. But now it seems we that we won't be leaking DB resources, but instead we will be spending a lot of time just opening and closing database connections. This can't be right, can it? Is the above code now opening and closing a DB connection **for every single log entry by our users**, adding even more overhead than just leaving the DataClassesDataContext to be garbage collected at a future time?

Answer (score 5):

Your question has a false premise: you're assuming that by not disposing of the context that you're leaving the connection open for other users. This is incorrect. All you're doing is deferring the *closing* of the connection until garbage collection; subsequent requests will *always* open a new connection if they're instantiating the context.

That being said, the context class is lightweight (as are database connection objects). Your connections are automatically pooled, so there is not necessarily a 1:1 ratio between database connection objects and actual database connections.

By properly disposing of the class by enclosing it in a using block, you're now using it correctly (no pun intended).